# Инсталляционный пакет для программы.

Tags: c#, ado.net

Здравствуйте. У меня есть программа, написана на c# и на нем подключена база данных. Теперь хочу создать инсталляционный пакет для этой программы, но не знаю как делать. Один раз создал пакет, но это было для игры и там не было базы данных. Подскажите, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала пишешь датабилдер, который будет создавать и заполнять твою базу, потом создаешь инсталяционный пакет самой программы куда и включаешь свой датабилдер.

Comment: Да, базу с собой возят редко, как максимум дамп базы.

Comment: а может знайте где нужно посмотреть, как пишут датабилдер?

Comment: Попробуй http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5498, программа, насколько я понял, создает дамп базы, а потом нужно просто написать выполнения скриптов. Можете попробовать Backup & Restore.

Comment: А не знайте где есть статия про тему, как написать этот скрипт?